# Extract the user-defined Error message from exception

Tags: sql, postgresql

Inside my stored procedure, i just checked a particular condition and i'll throw Exception if that condition fails. like below,

```
Raise Exception '%', 'Hello world';
```

It is working fine, But the error message Hello world also comes with some other error code like stuffs like below in my front end,

```
DA00014:ERROR: P0001: Hello world
|___________________|
        |
      I really dont want this part to get displayed in the front end.
```

Is there any proper way available to filter out/Extract the right message from thrown exception.?

[**Note:** *Please don't suggest me to do some string manipulations.*]

```
DBMS      : POSTGRESQL 9.0.3
Driver    : Npgsql 1.0
Front End : VB.net
```

Comment: And what's on the front end - language, drivers, etc.?

Comment: @MilenA.Radev language. By the way it is VB.net.

Comment: And the driver? Npgsql?

Comment: @MilenA.Radev i have updated that detail into my question

Comment: Some of the members of [Npgsql.NpgsqlException](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/1.0/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlException.html) or [Npgsql.NpgsqlError](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/1.0/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlError.html) should be what you are looking for.

Comment: @MilenA.Radev Can you give any samples regarding to that.?

Answer (score 1):

### Npgsql Fastpath

If `NpgsqlException.Errors` is null in your exception handler then you have most likely hit a bug in Npgsql Fastpath (well I consider it a bug anyway). [Here is the offending line](https://github.com/franciscojunior/Npgsql2/blob/master/src/NpgsqlTypes/FastPath.cs#L174) in version 2 but the same issue exists in version 1.

It basically boils down to this code where a proper `NpgsqlError` is constructed and then thrown away when raising the exception by calling `ToString()` on it.

```
NpgsqlError e = new NpgsqlError(conn.BackendProtocolVersion, stream);
throw new NpgsqlException(e.ToString());
```

The fix would be as simple as changing the code to this and using the already supported ability of `NpgsqlException` to take in a list of `NpgsqlError` in the constructor.

```
NpgsqlError e = new NpgsqlError(conn.BackendProtocolVersion, stream);
throw new NpgsqlException(new ArrayList(e));
```

So in summary you can't do it without string manipulation unless you compile your own version of Npgsql patching the issue.

### Npgsql

If you aren't using Fastpath then the thrown `NpgsqlException` object contains an `Errors` property which should be a non null list. This is an example of extracting the message from the first error.

```
(ex.Errors[0] as NpgsqlError).Message
```

Comment: Seems interesting, I'll try this out and post back the result soon.

Answer (score 0):

try this..
 Inside your store procedure place an extra character in message. e.g

```
Raise Exception '%', '|Hello world';
```

On Front end `split your message on character "|",` and display second index of array. e.g

```
    Try
      ' your code..
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim arr As String() = ex.Message.Split("|")
        If arr.Count > 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(arr(1)))
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(ex.Message))
        End If
    End Try
```

Comment: The Note which was given by OP at the bottom of the question

Comment: There is no other way to handle this, SQL Server also generate such type of Message, when **Raiserror in Trigger** is used.

Comment: `There is no other way to handle this`. Do you have any concrete proof for that?

Comment: No, i haven't, If you have any other better solution, please provide it.

Comment: No offense, I have been suffering from the same problem too, And i have been searching for a elegant way to handle this.

Comment: ok @SATSON, if you found some thing elegant, then plz also inform me, because i have also searched a lot for that, when i was suffering from that problem, but did not found any elegant way. So in past i have handled it the way i have shared.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood, you can try this once

```
IF condition match -- (your condition)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Hello world', 16,16)
    return
 END
```

and in expception

can use like

```
catch(exception ex)
{
  // ex.Message
  //  ex.InnerException.Message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Catch ex As Exception

    lblMsg.Text = ex.Message.Replace("ERROR: P0001: ", "")

End Try
```